# Cannot pull/push changes within VS 2015 Update 3 with Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssl

If I want to pull/push some code changes within Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I always get the following error:

```
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception:
    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I tried many things so far. With TortoiseGit and Giut itself all is working fine (but only after I set `git config --global http.sslVerify false`). What is the problem inside VS? On another PC, all is working fine...

Comment: please check the time machine if it is OK , SSL fail when the time in your machine does not correspond to the real time

Comment: @WejdDAGHFOUS My time is correct...